Wedge product combinatorics
I've read some valuable posts here on Math.SE, but still could not find a proper answer.
Consider the differential $r$-form $\alpha$ on $\mathbb R^n$, with $r<n$.
In a very common notation, this form appears as $$\alpha = \sum_I a_I dx^I$$ where $I$ is a multi-index, i.e. the set of sequences $i_1,...,i_r$ with $i_1 < i_2 <...<i_r$ and $i_r \in \{1...n\}$.
So, the number of monomials generated by this sum is given by the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{r}$.
Consider now a differential $s$-form $\beta$ on $\mathbb R^n$, with $n>r+s$.
In the same notation we could write $\beta$ as $$\beta = \sum_J b_J dx^J$$
Very often the wedge product of the two forms is concisely written as $$\alpha \wedge \beta = \sum_{IJ}a_Ib_Jdx^I \wedge dx^J$$
where the symbol "$IJ$" seems to indicate a product of binomials, which would generate $$\frac{n^2}{r!s!(n-r)!(n-s)!}$$ terms. This to me seems conceptually (and numerically) wrong, being the correct factor $$\frac{n!}{(r+s)!(n-r-s)!}$$.
What is the right answer?

You have an obvious typo in your definition of $\beta$. I don't follow, and I have no idea what a "product of binomials" is. It should be a sum over all $I,J$, and obviously we get $0$ if some index $i$ equals some index $j$.

Remember that $dx^I \wedge dx^J = 0$ whenever $I \cap J \neq \varnothing$.

Thank you @TedShifrin, I've corrected the typo. To me $IJ$ looked as $\binom{n}{r} \binom{n}{s}$ - this is what I grossly meant by "product of binomials"

No, you jumped to a crazy conclusion. They just mean the sum over all $I$ and $J$. Besides, $I$ and $J$ are sets of multiindices, and we certainly are not multiplying sets.

@TedShifrin fine, thank you!
